Formalization of the independance of products in a (commutative) semigroup
1/ It is well known that associativity implies that the result of the product of an ordered finite set of elements in a semigroup does not depend of the order of composition of the partial products.
Has any formalisation system verified this result ?
2/ Similarly, it is well-known that in a commutative semigroup, the product of a finite set of element does not depend of the order the elements are composed with.
Has ant formalisation system verified this result ?
